# Usize breaking zksync when compiling for ARM

Tags: rust, compilation, integer, arm, golem

This is a complex and hard issue, but I will break it down to the best of my abilities. It comes down to when I am compiling a rust project for ARM64 (goal is to run on rasp pi 4).

A large majority of the libraries compile (704 / 740) but it breaks during compilation when it goes to compile a [zksync](https://github.com/authereum/zksync) directory. The the [yagna client](https://github.com/golemfactory/yagna) for golem is what I am compiling, I am using

target - target.arm-unknown-linux-musleabi
linker - arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld

I'd love to hear ideas solutions, or what I am doing wrong so I can get this project running on ARM.
The error code I am getting is

```html
 Ok(stat.blocks_available() as u64 * stat.fragment_size())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `u64`, found `u32`
```

among other errors, all revolving around bit differences when converting integers. This had led to me suspecting usize to be the culprit as it bases size off CPU architecture, which would explain the ARM compilation messing it up, and not showing up until you have to handle the int (at conversion).

let me know if there is any more information you need, tried to my best to encapsulate the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat` is a [`Statvfs`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.18.0/nix/sys/statvfs/struct.Statvfs.html) structure, the return type of `Statvfs::blocks_available()` is `fsblkcnt_t`, and the return type of `Statvfs::fragment_size()` is `c_ulong`.  These two types are defined in the [`libc`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.63/libc/index.html) package, which is a paper-thin wrapper around the low-level C OS-calls. The types are equivalent to the C types in the OS-specific `*.h` files.  The sizes of the types vary from platform to platform.

The library you're compiling appears to have some assumptions baked in about these sizes and their arithmetic compatibility.

Some bug reports to the library authors would be in order.

If you're willing to patch the library yourself, then you should first investigate your platform's `libc` package and check the definitions of all types involved in the errors you're seeing.  Then fix the arithmetic expressions so the types are compatible and they don't overflow.

I don't think Rust's type system is smart enough to support one body of code that handles all potential combinations of type sizes both safely (without overflow or truncation) and efficiently (without needlessly casting everything up to u128) .  It might be that platform-specific patches are necessary.

Comment: So to clarify if I wanted to fork out the library to run on ARM I should investigate libc of this library and see what functions are associated with my errors? Then change all the of the math to account for integers on ARM and only ARM? Sorry, still new to rust and trying to understand where I should be focusing my efforts. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I think patching the library to work with every rust-supported platform may not be feasible.  The most feasible option I see is to try and focus just on your platforms (you mentioned a specific raspberry pi target, plus you probably want x86 to work for development & debug), share your patches upstream, and leave fixing the library architecture to them.

Comment: libc differs *platform by platform*.  Some of the type sizes on ARM64 will probably be different than those on your x86 development box.